# Rails 3 calendar_helper gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, rubygems

I have in my Gemfile this line:

```
gem 'calendar_helper', :git => 'git://github.com/topfunky/calendar_helper.git'
```

Everything is ok and working with this:

```
= calendar(:year => 2013, :month => 3, :first_day_of_week => 1)
```

But where is the file 'calendar_helper.rb'?
I have searched for it everywhere in my project folder, but I can't find it. And I need it to modify the calendar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :
bundle show calendar_helper or bundle open calendar_helper

Comment: Thank you, I found the file.
    ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bundler/gems/calendar_helper-763a497dbd88/lib/calendar_helper.rb

The bad thing is that I have to reboot the server every time I make a change on the file.
Is there any way to have a copy of this file in my project and use it in real time?

Answer (score 0):

Do `echo $GEM_PATH` on terminal. You will get `rvm gems path`. If you have `rvm` installed in `home` user. You will find `gems` in `~/.rvm/gems`. It will show different `gemsets`(as directory) you have created. Go to one which you are currently using. In that you will see `gems` directory. In that you will have all gems you using. In this you will see `calender_helper` directory which contains the related code.